# How to know which one the system is using: Software RAID or Hardware RAID or BIOS RAID

Tags: centos, raid

It's a xw6600 HP workstation running with CentOS 7 and RAID1. I have to replace the current 2TB array with 6TB array.

I'd like to know, once the replacement's done, how can we manage the array, check whether it's syncing, it's done the sync or how far of the progress the sync is... For each type of RAID, we have the corresponding utilities doing so. But no hint about which RAID the system is using: Hardware/Software/BIOS.

**Is there any way to determine which RAID my system is using?**

Some used commands and output which are somehow odd:

```
[root@data ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities :
unused devices: <none>

[root@data ~]# dmraid -s
no raid disks

[root@data ~]# mdadm --detail-platform
       Platform : Intel(R) Rapid Storage Technology
        Version : 5.6.2.1002
    RAID Levels : raid0 raid1 raid10 raid5
    Chunk Sizes : 4k 8k 16k 32k 64k 128k
    2TB volumes : not supported
      2TB disks : not supported
      Max Disks : 6
    Max Volumes : 2 per array, 4 per controller
 I/O Controller : /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2 (SATA)
          Port0 : - non-disk device (TSSTcorp DVD-ROM TS-H353B) -
          Port1 : - no device attached -
          Port2 : - no device attached -
          Port3 : - no device attached -
          Port4 : - no device attached -
          Port5 : - no device attached -

[root@data ~]# lspci -vv | grep -i raid
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB SATA RAID Controller (rev 09)

[root@data ~]# lsscsi
[2:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  TSSTcorp DVD-ROM TS-H353B BC05  /dev/sr0
[8:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD20EURS-73T 0A80  -
[8:0:1:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD20EURS-63S AB51  -
[8:1:1:0]    disk    LSILOGIC Logical Volume   3000  /dev/sda

[root@data ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.0 GB, 1999999336448 bytes, 3906248704 sectors
Disk label type: dos

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048  3906248703  1952611328   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 8455 MB, 8455716864 bytes, 16515072 sectors
Disk /dev/mapper/centos-home: 1400.4 GB, 1400381636608 bytes, 2735120384 sectors
Disk /dev/mapper/centos-backup: 536.9 GB, 536942215168 bytes, 1048715264 sectors
```

More info: This is a workstation, but used for a small data server of the company. There is not much documentation about it, the sysadmin just quit his job and I replace his position. I can reach BIOS but it must be the last choice since the machine is in production (24/7 online).

Comment: Considering there is a raid controller, you're probably using it to do some raid with it. Might also be in passthrough mode so you can do some software raid with the raw disks ?

Comment: @Tolsadus There is a RAID card inside the machine, and two disks are connected to the card by SATA cables. I didn't get the passthrought mode that you said. Assuming it's a software raid, why does `mdadm --detail-platform` show `no device attached`...

Comment: Indeed, that's odd. Not 100% sure about that. Do you have perhaps an iLO access or something similar to grab and get more informations ? (without the need to reboot the machine)

Comment: If there's a _hardware_ RAID card, then it probably isn't _software_ RAID. Check `lspci -nn`

Comment: @MichaelHampton `lspci -nn` shows up an `SCSI storage controller`, named `LSI Logic / Symbios Logic SAS1064ET PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS` which is exactly the same brand printed on the RAID card. After digging the whole HP's support page, I've just found that xw6600 is using LSI 3041E card, and it's **Hardware-assisted RAID** (or BIOS RAID).

@Tolsadus, unfortunately, no, all I have is the ssh connection (and full root privileges)